# Таблицы в latex

Tags: latex, таблицы

столкнулась с такой проблемой при построении таблицы: не прорисовываются до конца все линии. В чем причина понять не могу. Может кто знающий подскажет. 
Код:

```
 \begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}    
    \hline      
    \multirow{Сооружения} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Размещение горных выработок} & \multirow{Глубина горных выработок}\\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    {}  & Расстояние по оси трассы, м &  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Расстояние    } & {}\\ \cline{3-4}
     {}  & {}  &  на поперечниках, м   &  между поперечниками, м  &   {}\\ \end{tabular}
```

Вот так выглядит таблица:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. горизонтальные вы сами не дорисовываете: у вас пять колонок, а рисуете только до четвёртой. 2. вертикальные линии имеют разрыв потому, что вы вставили пустую ячейку (вероятно, лишнюю, про что вам latex, кстати, рассказывает при компиляции) после ячейки с текстом "расстояние".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас ошибки в коде. 
Ниже рабочий, сравните.

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{2.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|}    
    \hline      
    \multirow{3}{*}{Сооружения} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Размещение горных выработок} & \multirow{3}{*}{Глубина горных выработок}\\ 
    \cline{2-4}
    {} & Расстояние по оси трассы, м & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Расстояние}\\ 
    \cline{3-4}
    {} & {} & на поперечниках, м & между поперечниками, м & {}\\ 
    \hline
 \end{tabular}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)